# Equation is not evaluating any result

Tags: discrete-mathematics, math-software, maple

eq1 := $y = -26.21231979*z+15.42332896+13.22411533*e^{-.6786000000*x}$

eq2 := $y = -25.98077423*z+14.81943362+13.53858145*e^{-.6569000000*x}$

Comparing both equations, eliminating $y$

$-26.21231979*z+15.42332896+13.22411533*e^{-.6786000000*x}$ = $-25.98077423*z+14.81943362+13.53858145*e^{-.6569000000*x}$

Putting $z$= $0.5044$

$-26.21231979*(0.5044)+15.42332896+13.22411533*e^{-.6786000000*x} $=
$ -25.98077423*(0.5044)+14.81943362+13.53858145*e^{-.6569000000*x}$

I cannot find $x$ value? I tried it in Maple as well. But it doesn't evaluate the value of $x$. Any other solution?

Edit : My main task is to calculate value of $x$  by putting any value of $z$
This is just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you believe that there is a value of `x` that satisfies you equations when `z=0.5044`?

```
eq1 := y=-26.21231979*z+15.42332896+13.22411533*exp(-0.6786*x):
eq2 := y=-25.98077423*z+14.81943362+13.53858145*exp(-0.6569*x):
q := rhs(eq1)-rhs(eq2);
plot3d( [0,q], x=-0.001..0.001, z=0.4..1.4,view=-1..1,color=[red,blue] );
plot3d( [0,q], x=-10..10, z=0.4..1.4,view=-1..1,color=[red,blue] );
Optimization:-Minimize(z,{q<=0,q>=0},x=-0.001..0.001, z=1.1..1.3);
```

The surfaces computed by the above `plot3d` calls do not seem to fall below (or touch) height 0.0 unless `z` is at least some value greater than 1. Something above `z=1.2496` or so. Do you have a reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: Nice observation.  The bound $z=1.184210000$ can be found by differentiating both sides of the equation by $x$, solving for $x$, then substituting this back into the original equation and solving for $z$.

Answer (score 1):

In Maple, use the command **fsolve**. Remember to use **exp(x)** for $e^x$.

Comment: I tried this command as well

$ fsolve(eval(rhs(eq1) = rhs(eq2), z = 0.5044)$

Comment: Did you use **exp** for $e$?

Comment: Yes. I input $exp$ as well

Comment: Plotting leads me to believe, like Acer, that there is no solution for this $z$.

Comment: @Carl.. okay!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the value you gave to "z" is wrong or that your coefficients are wrong. Using the numbers given in your post, there is no solution to your problem. In order to have a solution close to x=0.501, "z" should be of the order of 1.18421 (as reported by acer). The difference of your two equations goes to an extemum for x = 0.414684 and for this value this difference has a value equal to (-0.274199 + 0.231546 z).

Comment: okay!! I got it. I agree with acer.. I will put $z= 1.184221$. But my main issue is why this tool is not evaluating value of $x$ ??

Comment: @Syeda. If there is no solution to your equation, what do you want Maple to do ?

Comment: @Claude.. okay!!  Its means my approach is wrong! :(
Thankyou..